# MS Deploy - Team Build Drop

Tags: iis, tfs, tfsbuild, msdeploy

Does MS Deploy support the following scenario?

1. Create a package from a Team Build drop
2. Install the web application into IIS6/7 including app pools, settings, etc.

It doesn't seem to want to let me configure IIS on the destination server if my package wasn't created from IIS originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current feature set does not support this scenario - Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the parameter DeployOnBuild set to true, then your build will produce not only your normal web site files under _PublishedWebSites, but also one whose name ends with _Package. That will contain your package, the parameters file and the manifest, plus a .cmd file for deploying the package.

What it will *not* contain is anything you didn't tell MSBUILD to place into the package. In particular, no, it won't contain IIS settings unless you told MSBUILD to place IIS settings there. It won't get the settings from out of the air - it will only get them from your local IIS, and only if that's where you have your project set up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the DeployOnBuild parameter doesn't work for our situation.  I'm creating the package in a custom build activity after many post-build activities take place (CSS compression, assembly versioning, etc).

I am hoping I can set up IIS using MS Deploy only packaging my Team Build drop folder.

Comment: See [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Build-Engine-Foundation/dp/0735645248/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1320424948&sr=8-1). There are mechanisms for this. You don't have to hack it.

Comment: I've already read the relevant chapters from that book (17-19) - it's probably the best material out there for MSDeploy but still not great.  I reached out to Vishal Joshi and the MSDeploy product group at Microsoft and unfortunately there are not "mechanisms" for what I'm trying to accomplish.  He stated the team is working on alternate solutions but that this is a limitation from the currently released feature sets.  Thanks for your input though.